# LAN-only IP-to-IP video chat

Tags: chat, video-conferencing, lan

I'm searching a LAN-Only messenger, with the following features

- audio
- video
- text works without internet
- type in the IP-address of another computer and it connects to that computer's messenger.
- Python-script also ok
- Plattform: Windows (bonus: ubuntu, bonusbonus: ios)

I'm aware, that there are similar topics on this question, although their solution is "big" - like client-server seperated programms (Jitsi+Openfire).

We had something similar for Windows about 10 years ago ("Net[something]"). But now even after a 2 hour search I can't find easy and quick-to-use solutions

Comment: Related and thus worth a look: [Simple serverless messenger for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2967/185) is also asking for P2P messengers, though with a different scope. But it might well be that there's some overlapping.

Comment: Jave you tried Jitsi? IIRC it can use the local network too.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend trying a WebRTC based solution. One of them is [apprtc](https://appr.tc/).

You'll need internet connection to load the web page once, But after that you can talk to who ever you want on your local network without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally familiar with it, but **SSuite FaceCom Portal** may fit your need for the video calling part.

http://www.ssuitesoft.com/instantvideolanchat.htm

> There is no internet connection necessary to use and run this
>   application.

---

For text and voice chat **Squiggle** seems good http://squiggle.codeplex.com/

- Group chat
- File transfer

And more.

---

For text only messaging **LAN Messenger** is a popular one.

Is available for Ubuntu.

http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PopMessenger](http://www.leadmind.com). It can send private and public text messages. Can work without Internet connection. File sending is supported.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with PopMessenger.

Answer (score 0):

Just for being a tad different, I'd consider setting up BigBlueButton on your LAN somewhere and giving your users their own conference rooms.  BBB is a online meeting room/video conference tool, Free software from Google's Summer of Code a while back.

Allows voice/video as well as text chat, document sharing, document notation/scribbling over them with drawing tools, desktop or application sharing.  And you can invite more than one user in.  In the right spot on your LAN it would even be possible to (temporarily) allow access to a vendor, etc.